# automatically run ls after changing path using autocd

Tags: command-line, bash, ls, zsh

So everytime I change the directory I would like the new path to automatically get listed with `ls`.
There are solutions if the path gets changed using `cd` but I never found a solution that would work when the path gets changed using the `autocd` option.

Would be quite convenient, has anyone achieved that before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND`, which is executed before PS1, e.g.:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='ls'
```

This will list each time you get a new prompt.  Of course you only want to execute `ls` if the directory has changed:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $my_currdir != $PWD ]] && ls; my_currdir=$PWD'
```

This checks if the new directory isn't the same as the last one set, and then executes `ls`, after which your current directory is stored in `my_currdir`

I found an even better line [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=108553%29%3a), where they use [bash as a file manager](http://pastebin.com/VBSQJyeA):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ ${__new_wd:=$PWD} != $PWD ]] && list; __new_wd=$PWD'
```

since it is possible that `__new_wd` is unset, you can assign a default value which will be used in that case (see `bash` man pages, search for `:=`)